# Is there any way to add user in linux which has no permission to any folder in system except a specific folder

Tags: php, linux, centos7

Is there any way to add user in linux(Cent os 7) which has no permission to any folder in system except a specific folder? 
I wana to use that user to run php-fpm, and keep other file safe. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please avoid saying "thank you" in your questions. That's not necessary.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Might be better suited on the Superuser stack exchange site.

Comment: No, there are always system-wide-readable files/directories.  You might want to look at the possibility of running it in a `chroot jail` or even just proper filesystem ownership/permission changes, a shell of `/bin/false`, etc